# Django or PHP for Web/Mobile App with AWS

Tags: android, django, amazon-web-services

So I will be using AWS for a future project, and I have been struggling on getting the right infrastructure. The project will consist of a web application, android app, and iPad app. Now, I have done PHP and Python before, but I keep hearing how bad PHP is and new webapps should be done in Python or RoR. Fine with me, I love Python!

Now, if I have a Django instance running on a EC2 instance for the web application, will it be easy to interact with it via Java/Android? Or should I just use the AWS Android SDK to interact with S3 and SimpleDB/RDS and use the PHP SDK, so I wouldn't be paying for a EC2 instance?

Basically here are the two options:

1) Django instance running on a EC2 instance, that controls everything. Will be used to communicate with the browsers and Android App.
2) No EC2 instance. Use the PHP SDK and Android SDK to communicate with the AWS.

I feel like 2) would be easier, since the Android SDK and PHP SDK will communicate directly with the AWS. But, I can use the Python SDK in 1) to communicate with the AWS. Therefore, I would have one point of entry to maintan.

I hope the question makes sense... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should have some sort of web app (Django is fine, PHP would work too) between your devices and your database.

There's many reasons for this (maintainability, caching, upgrading, etc), but this one is the most important:  If you don't, all instances of your Android app will have your SimpleDB/RDS access credentials... that would be really easy for someone to pull out of your app and misuse.

Comment: Therefore, interacting directly from Android to AWS using the Java SDK is not really a good solution? I should make use of a app in between like you are saying right? How easy do you think is the interacting from Android to a Django app? I guess it would simply be HTTP request interpreted as JSON?

Comment: Yes.    There are many ways to do it, but at a basic level it's not too hard.  If you need help on that, google around for some tutorials and ask more questions on SO